# Is it possible to make the Book Outline a mandatory field when creating a new book page?

Tags: 7, nodes

I would like to make sure that certain content types **always** have a parent book/page.

Is there a way to do this, by JavaScript, by modifying the book module or whatever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do it, without to modify book.module. (Modifying Drupal files is never a good idea.)

You can create a custom module that contains code similar to the following:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (!empty($form['book']['bid'])) {
    $form['book']['bid']['#element_validate'][] = 'mymodule_book_validate';
  }
}

/**
 * Form validation handler for book_form_node_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_book_validate($element, $form_state) {
  // Check other conditions you need to check.
  if ($element['#value'] == 0) {
    form_error($element, t('You must select a book.'));
  }
}
```

The code I wrote allows you to check other conditions before to report the error; for example, you could allow users with the permission to administer books to not assign a book to the book page. You could also verify other conditions like the node title, the permissions assigned to the user who is creating the book page, the presence of keywords in the text used as body of the node, etc.

Comment: Hey, I tried creating a new module called booktest and, when I save a book page without a parent I get the error: "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in _form_validate() (line 1336 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal-7.0test/includes/form.inc)." Any idea what it could be?

Comment: @Spre3: Usually that means the code changed a value that Drupal is expecting to be an array with a value of a different datatype.

Comment: the error is coming from the line:  "$form['book']['bid']['#element_validate'] = 'booktest_book_validate';"
is this line meant to assign the validation function to that element of the form? I dont understand it.

Comment: @Spre3: I forgot to add `[]`. `$form['book']['bid']['#element_validate']` is an array; that is the reason why you get that error when you replace its value with a string. I fixed my answer. I apologize for not having noticed before the code I wrote was not correct.

Comment: Fantastic, that worked! Also had to change if ($element['#value'] == t('none')) to if ($element['#value'] == "0") and it's now working, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT: On review, I see this question is D7 specific. There may be subtle things wrong with my code snippet. It should be fundamentally the same.**

If something should never happen, I prefer to make it never-an-option.

If you want to make all book pages default to being new books:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() for node_form.
 */
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if (book_type_is_allowed($form['#node']->type)) {
    // Remove the "none" option.
    unset($form['book']['bid']['#options'][0]);
  }
}
```

Once that's done, you can leave it be or set `$form['book']['bid']['#default_value']` explicitly to be a new book, or a specified book bid of your choice. It will probably naturally fall into creating new books, as that is the first option in the selector after you remove *none*.

Comment: The reason why I can't use this its because children will be creating pages and I can't trust them to always choose the right book unless it's right in front of their eyes and even then it's probably not going to work 100%

Comment: Choosing the right book is a related question, but I'd call them completely different issues. The accepted answer achieves basically the same thing by warning them off from the option you don't like, instead of preempting the problem by removing the option.